# Can I use a factory function in NextJS and can it be asynchronous?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a factory function in a Next.js app that fetches data from an API and returns some functions that make use of that data.

When I export the factory function and try to use any of the functions I am returning from the factory function in a separate file, I get this error:

```
Property 'validateAmount' does not exist on type '() => Promise<{ validateAmount: (value: unknown) => any; validateMessage: (value: unknown) => any; validateSender: (value: unknown) => any; { ...; }) => {...'
```

```js
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { getData } from '../api/data';

export const factory = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  
  const MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 300;
  const MAX_SENDER_LENGTH = 20;
  const MIN_AMOUNT = 1;
  const MAX_AMOUNT = data.maxValue;
  const schema = {
    amount: yup
      .number()
      .typeError('amount is required.')
      .required('amount is required')
      .min(MIN_AMOUNT, 'Gift card amount cannot be zero')
      .max(
        MAX_AMOUNT,
        `Please note that the maximum amount allowed is R${MAX_AMOUNT}`
      ),

    message: yup.string().required('Message is required').max(MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH),
    sender: yup.string().required('Sender is required').max(MAX_SENDER_LENGTH),
    retailer: yup.object({ id: yup.string().required('Please select a retailer below') }),
  };

 
  const validator = (schema: yup.AnySchema) => (value: unknown) => {
    try {
      schema.validateSync(value);
      return '';
    } catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  };

  const validateAmount = validator(schema.amount);
  const validateMessage = validator(schema.message);
  const validateSender = validator(schema.sender);
  const validateRetailer = validator(schema.retailer);

  return {
    validateAmount,
    validateMessage,
    validateSender,
    validateRetailer,
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling the `factory` function? Are you awaiting for the promise it returns to resolve?

Comment: Yes @juliomalves , I call it this way in an async function:

`await factory. validateAmount(value)`